# Missing Chameleon module in Pyramid Tutorial

Tags: python, pyramid, chameleon

I'm following the [Pyramid tutoral](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_tutorials/en/latest/humans/creatingux/step01/index.html#goals).

I've also gone through the setup without any errors reported [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_tutorials/en/latest/humans/setup.html)

But I get this when attempting to run the app.

```
File "/home/xy/pyramid/tutorial_workspace/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py2.7.egg/pyramid/chameleon_text.py", line 3, in <module>
    from chameleon.zpt.template import PageTextTemplateFile
ImportError: No module named chameleon.zpt.template
```

Although the `easy_install pyramid WebTest nose` should have covered the chameleon dependency?

Has anyone else come across this? Should I attempt to install chameleon independently?

Comment: The [setup.py for pyramid](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/setup.py) includes Chameleon. What does `ls /home/xy/pyramid/tutorial_workspace/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` show?

Comment: ls -m /home/xy/pyramid/tutorial_workspace/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg, easy-install.pth, Mako-0.7.3-py2.7.egg, PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.7.egg, pip-1.1-py2.7.egg, pyramid-1.4-py2.7.egg,
repoze.lru-0.6-py2.7.egg, setuptools.pth, translationstring-1.1-py2.7.egg, venusian-1.0a7-py2.7.egg, WebOb-1.2.3-py2.7.egg,
zope.deprecation-4.0.2-py2.7.egg, zope.interface-4.0.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg

Comment: Interesting, no Chameleon. Try `bin/pip install Chameleon` next, in the virtual env.

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks - looks like it's stopped auto-installing from 'easy_install pyramid WebTest nose'

Comment: Perhaps there was an error and it stopped halfway through?

Comment: Nope, I tried it a bunch of times, it just reads the pypi site but doesn't actually download or install anything. Processing dependencies for pyramid
Searching for Chameleon>=1.2.3
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/Chameleon/
Reading http://chameleon.repoze.org
error: None
How do I +1 you for this?